# 404 Not Found Spring Boot application using spring cloud starter security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I am currently following a Pluralsight tutorial about Java Microservices with Spring Cloud Security. After I run this application, I copy the generated security password from log and in Postman i am calling 
    http://localhost:9001/services/tolldata using Basic Auth with user: user and password: the generated one. But it gives as response 404 Not Found.

I have tried to change port from application settings, the same result.
Tried to add also the host address in properties, the same result.
Deleted the server.servlet.context-path, same result.
Placed the    @RequestMapping("/tolldata") above the getTollData() method, same result.

This is my main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/tolldata")
public class TollUsage{
    public String id;
    public String stationId;
    public String licensePlate;
    public String timestamp;

    public List<TollUsage> getTollData(){
        TollUsage instance1 = new TollUsage("100", "station150", "B65GT1W", "2016-09-30T06:31:22");
        TollUsage instance2 = new TollUsage("101", "station119", "AHY673B", "2016-09-30T06:32:50");
        TollUsage instance3 = new TollUsage("102", "station150", "ZN2GP0", "2016-09-30T06:37:01");

        List<TollUsage> tolls = new ArrayList<TollUsage>();
        tolls.add(instance1);
        tolls.add(instance2);
        tolls.add(instance3);

        return tolls;
    }

    public TollUsage(){}

    public TollUsage(String id, String stationId, String licensePlate, String timestamp){
        this.id = id;
        this.stationId = stationId;
        this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

}

This is my application.properties

```
server.port=9001
server.servlet.context-path=/services
```

And finally the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `@RestController` on your `TollUsage` class, not `DemoApplication` and split these classes to diffrent files.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This fixed the problem. I have learned something new today. I will accept as the solution answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tolldata")
@RestController
    class TollUsage{
        public String id;
        public String stationId;
        public String licensePlate;
        public String timestamp;

        @GetMapping
        @CrossOrigin
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<List<TollUsage>> getTollData(){
            TollUsage instance1 = new TollUsage("100", "station150", "B65GT1W", "2016-09-30T06:31:22");
            TollUsage instance2 = new TollUsage("101", "station119", "AHY673B", "2016-09-30T06:32:50");
            TollUsage instance3 = new TollUsage("102", "station150", "ZN2GP0", "2016-09-30T06:37:01");

            List<TollUsage> tolls = new ArrayList<TollUsage>();
            tolls.add(instance1);
            tolls.add(instance2);
            tolls.add(instance3);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(tolls, HttpStatus.OK);;
        }

        public TollUsage(){}

        public TollUsage(String id, String stationId, String licensePlate, String timestamp){
            this.id = id;
            this.stationId = stationId;
            this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: TollUsage is still not a controller, this will not work. TollUsage needs @RestController annotation.

Comment: @schanakira you are right i forget it (i am a little busy that's why ) thx , it's fixed !